# Automating update of network dataset in ArcGIS Server

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy

I am trying to set up an automated process that does a nightly extract of the network dataset from SDE and publish to:

1. ArcGIS Server 10.3 as a network service
2. fGDB as network dataset

It seems you can't dissolve a network dataset in SDE so you have to move it to a fGDB. Ideally I would have liked to copy and paste from SDE directly into a fGDB but can't find a way to automate this. I have done the following as a work around:

1. Arcpy script that imports data to fGDB, updates FCID
2. Manually create new network dataset in fGDB
3. Arcpy script that updates alternate ID and dissolves network
4. Manually push network dataset to ArcGIS Server (will script this)

I would be interested to hear in other peoples experiences in

Comment: It's complicated because of the network, I would copy the data as data and then build the network in the fGDB. Topologies are like that too. Have you tried copying the whole feature dataset? What about workspace to XML (with data) then XML to workspace?

Comment: I have tried arcpy.CopyFeatures_management as per @Alex (see below). I will XML export/import.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Copy GP tool for copying the entire feature dataset where the ND resides + it will copy all the related ND tables found in the geodatabase (outside of FD).

This will preserve the ND and you don't need to create one. You are correct that it is not allowed to run the Dissolve network on an ND stored within the SDE geodatabase, you do need to run this on a file gdb.

Comment: @ Alex I have tried arcpy.CopyFeatures_management and it pulls everything except the Network Feature dataset.`featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
outWorkspace = r"C:\Data.gdb\test"
for features in featureClasses:
    outFeatureClass = os.path.join(outWorkspace, features)
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(features, outFeatureClass)`

Comment: Who told you to use the CopyFeatures? :) Use the Copy tool (read carefully my answer) :)

Comment: The tool is Copy_management http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000051000000 to copy the feature dataset that the network resides in. There may be other feature classes you don't want but you can delete them later. If that does not work to your satisfaction use the XML workspace export/import... you can choose what feature classes, tables and relations to export.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. The import and export of XML is taking around 4 hours. I have tried 'arcpy.Copy_management'and keep getting stuck in a loop of errors (mainly 000260). The work around at this stage is copy and paste :-( I will revisit this in the future.